# limits.h unacknowledged values in C

Tags: c++, c, memory, byte, theory

I want to discover if there is a limit value designated to `ULLONG_MIN`.

I know there is a `ULLONG_MAX` which has the value `18446744073709551615` or `2^{64}-1`.

Does this mean that a theoretical `ULLONG_MIN` would be equivalent to `-(2^{64}-1)`?

I tried displaying it to the console by `unsigned long ULLONG_MIN = -(pow(2,64)-1);` and on my machine I get `9223372036854775808` which is probably half. Is it, because 64 bits cannot hold from -2^{64} to 2^{64}?

Comment: It probably is because __unsigned__ can't hold negative numbers.

Comment: yep, ULLONG_MIN  is 0

Comment: Oh yes of course not, its unsigned. But it would be 0? If I were to say -(ULLONG_MAX) it gives me a 1 not 0.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPAlh_FmO4M explains why it's 1.

Comment: @Computer -(ULLONG_MAX) gives you 1 because of the 2's complement operation that the computer performs in order to obtain a "negative" version of the number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Oh and by the way, __signed__ numbers use one bit for the sign, so it would be a range of `-2^63` to `2^63-1`.

Comment: For -(ULLONG_MAX) you can ask a separate question. I quote from the C++ specification: "The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2^{n}, where n is the number of bits
in the promoted operand." C should be similar. The point is, `-` does not do what you expect it to do on unsigned numbers.

Comment: @tkausl: Sign bits are quite rare in integer representations. x86, ARM and other common architectures all use twos' complement. _Floating point_ numbers generally do have sign bits, though. You can generally spot the use of two's complement because the range is asymmetric. `-2^63 to 2^63-1` is a typical example of 2's complement; with a sign bit that range would have been `-2^63+1 to 2^63-1`

Comment: Cowards, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

[ULLONG_MAX is a constant that defines the maximum value for an unsigned long long int.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

The minimum value of any unsigned number is by definition 0. Unsigned numbers cannot have negative values.